# c++ generic pointer? void pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am writing a program that can take in either 3 ints, or 3 floats in the constructor(I suppose I will need 2 constructors for this).  I want to declare an array and store the values in the array "numbers".

If I don't know which constructor will be called I am not sure how to declare "numbers"(as an int array or as a float array).

Is there a good technique to get around this? or can I create an int array and a float array and somehow have a generic pointer to the array being used(is using a void pointer the best way to do this)?

Comment: If the template suggestions do not work for you, then you probably need to reevaluate your design.  For instance, a `double` can hold a surprisingly large number of integer values precisely; do you really need to distinguish between the two cases?

Comment: What does this class do? Once you have created the object, will the user care which type it is using? - For example, if this is a vector class, you'd make it a regular type and perhaps provide conversions between different instantiations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want a templated class.

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T a, T b, T c)
    {
        numbers[0] = a;
        numbers[1] = b;
        numbers[2] = c;
    }
private:
    T numbers[3];
};
```

Comment: I think you might still explain, how you determine at runtime which instantiation to use.

Comment: @UncleBens well that obviously depends on the problem domain ... you want one with `int`s, use `Foo<int>`, you want one with 'double's, use `Foo<double>`, etc.

Comment: My point was: here the decision is made at compile-time. The asker leaves an impression that he wants to make the decision at runtime. - Of course, it seems pretty much impossible to answer not knowing what he's asking for.

Comment: @UncleBens Ah yes I see. It really depends on what this is needed for. You could derive this template class from some FooBase, but I don't really see what functionality could exist in the base class as Foo only includes stuff based on the templates. Basically, yeah - need more info!

Comment: Can you tell me why this only works if the constructor code in inline? Can I not put define it in the .cpp file?

Comment: A template class isn't actually a class. It's a recipe the compiler can use to generate a class. You can't have bits of the template class invisible to any translation unit, because then the compiler won't know how to generate the code for the class. Personally, I just use .h and .hpp files mostly. I don't really see the need for very many .cpp files at all, especially seeing as how poorly they play with templates.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you use templates for that?

example:

```
template <class T> 
class Foo {
    public Foo(T a, T b, T c);
};
//
Foo<float> aaa(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
Foo<int> bbb(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: How would you choose at runtime which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to make

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(double a, double b, double c)
        :_a(a), _b(b), _c(c)
    {}

    virtual double get_a() {return _a;}
    virtual double get_b() {return _b;}
    virtual double get_c() {return _c;}
    // more methods

protected:
    double _a, _b, _c;
};
```

works well for both ints and floats:

```
Foo ifoo(1, 3, 5);
Foo ffoo(2.0, 4.0, 6.0);
```

and for mixing them:

```
Foo mfoo(1, 4.0, 5);
```

**douable** storage space is more than enouh for both **int** and **float**